# VS Code automatically adds parenthesis around await statement

Tags: selenium-webdriver, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, async-await

I'm writing some tests in selenium webdriver js. I start by typing:

```
it('blah blah blah', async () => {
    await driver
})
```

Then I type `.` after `driver`. Suggestions come up. Then I select `findElement` from the list.

Then VS Code "intelligently" changes my code to:

```
await (await driver).findElement
```

This is annoying, as I have to manually remove the additional parenthesis and await. Any fix for this?

Comment: Did you ever find out why this was happening?

Comment: I'm also having this problem, and this is the only place where I found someone asking the same question. Have you figured it out?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and will follow-up with code. To be clear, if I undo the annoying:
`const userMenu = await (await driver).findElement`, and return it to what I typed, and not what VSCode decided I meant, `const userMenu = await driver.findElement`, it works. Everything works. I'm logging in, opening stuff, interacting with forms. All is well, other than this pesky auto-text `(await driver)` being inserted after I write `findElement`.

```
chrome.setDefaultService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromedriver.path).build());

const driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome().set('chromeOptions', {'args': ['--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs', '--start-maximized']}))
    // .setChromeOptions()
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is coming from `@wdio/globals/types`. You can resolve it by removing it from `compilerOptions` in your jsonconfig.json file.

Comment: Doesnt work for me :(

Answer (score -1):

My guess is that you forgot to resolve `new Builder().build()`, so your `driver` was actually a Promise. Could you give the full code?

Comment: Why, then, would all my code sucessfully automate processes after fixing the `await (await driver).findElement`? I'm having the same issue.